# How can I allow IP in htaccess from Vagrantfile

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am attempting to limit wp-admin access to a specific set of IPs.  This works great on the live server, but when viewing locally I am getting a `403 forbidden` error.

The site is developed using Vagrant and so I have set the following line in the `Vagrantfile`

```
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.120.33.15"
```

So in `/wp-admin` I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.120.33.15
```

I have attempted many variations and loading multiple IPs with no luck.  Any suggestions on how I can gain access when viewing the site locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure a private network as you mentioned

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.120.33.15"
```

you can connect to your host on the following interface `192.120.33.1`. Simply add this IP then in your `.htaccess` file and you will be able to access your webserver from your host.

Comment: Thanks!  Why wouldn't it work with the `192.120.33.15`?  I would have thought that this would have been more specific and allowed the exact IP rather than the range.

Comment: `192.120.33.15` is the IP of the VM server, so you would access only from your guest. Guest and Host does not have the same IP, you want to tell to your guest web server that request from the host are allowed